# One drive file name limit

Tags: windows, mac, onedrive, cloud-storage

I know that the one drive sync client for Mac has a size limit on the full file name including the files path, because I receive many errors about file paths being to long.
Does Windows have the same file name limit for One Drive?

Comment: [In Windows it is 260](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: [More detailed info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx)